# Android Realm initialization in project

Tags: android, database, realm

As seen in the official documentation on how to use Realm

```
// Initialize Realm
Realm.init(context);

// Get a Realm instance for this thread
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

I added dependencie to my project

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2"
```

I can use this library normally but **static method init apparently does not exist**. Can someone post an example of how to initialize and save example object to database using this library? There's really not too many tutorials and the usage looks really easy after you manage to fire it up. Realm initialization sets up default configuration right? So is there a way to bypass that static init and set it manually?

--EDIT

When I'm trying to execute this code

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
```

I get

> Error:(33, 49) error: Builder(Context) is not public in Builder; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: Did you `apply plugin: 'realm-android'`?

Comment: Yes, I can freely use this library, all methods and objects are there, but static init is not.

Comment: did you really go through the docs?home page of realm.io android java docs beautifully explains the use of realm for beginners

Comment: Yea, I tried to follow it but i stuck on this initialization thing

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This constructor no longer exists:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
```

Use this instead:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
```

The example you refer to should have been updated as well?

Comment: It didn't solved my original question but it helped others, so let it be, accepted answer ;)

Comment: How to set Modules RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .setModules(new SimpleRealmModule())
                .build();
.

Comment: User `.modules(new SimpleRealmModule())` https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas

Comment: How can we make the common object for RealmConfiguration throughout app?

Answer (score 0):

For me the actual problem was that Android studio couldn't update the library from some old version I initially connected to the project. Gradle had good version but actual libs files were old, solution for me was to manually re-download the files of this library.